# Reactive kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, reactive-kafka

Am exploring reactive kafka and just wanted to confirm if reactive kafka is equivalent to sync producer. With sync producer, We get message delivery guarantee with ACK all and producer sequence is maintained. But, delivery and sequencing is not guaranteed with ASYNC. Is reactive producer equivalent to SYNC or ASYNC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive means async. In plain Kafka clients API also, the `KafkaProducer` is asynchronous. It becomes synchronous when you explicitly call the `kafkaProducer.send().get()` which blocks the execution of the program.

Even with async producer, message delivery is guaranteed. It depends on the no. of retries and the `delivery.timeout.ms`.

With `ack=all` it is ensured that data is replicated among the ISR and you get fault-tolerance with consistency guarantees, in case if one of the broker dies, the consumers see what is intended to be seen.

As for the sequence, messages are batched before they are sent. If multiple batches are sent asynnchronously like *batch-1*, *batch-2*, *batch-3* and if for some reason *batch-1* fails after *batch-2* and *batch-3* have been sent, then retying *batch-1* will produce *batch-1* after *batch-2*, *batch-3*, thereby making it out of sequence.

If you want sequence, you need to ensure that [max.in.flight.requests.per.connection](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#max.in.flight.requests.per.connection) set to `1` so that only one request can be in-flight at any given instant of time per producer. However, this can have performance impact. You may want to tune other settings like `batch.size` like increasing it for example, to get increased throughput with the inflight requests set to 1.

So your assumption that delivery and sequencing is not guaranteed with ASYNC is false.